# How to use variable name to create new variables in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, joomla, json

I'm using Joomla Framework to create component that displays options from a MySQL table.
Because each option has a lot of various parameters they are being set as json arrays in **custparams** field.

This function extracts these custom parameters from each option based on option id.

JSON data is decoded and written into stdObject:

```
$_oparams=null;
function _custParamsOpt($pid)
{       
    $query='SELECT custparams FROM #__mycomponent_options'
                .' WHERE id = '.(int)$pid;
    $this->_db->setQuery( $query);
    $paramdata=$this->_db->loadResult();

    if (!empty($paramdata))
    {
        $custom=json_decode($paramdata);
        foreach ($custom as $custom_params)
        {
            if ($custom_params->pkey=='elemvert') $this->_oparams->elemvert=$custom_params->pvalue;
            if ($custom_params->pkey=='elemhor') $this->_oparams->elemhor=$custom_params->pvalue;
            if ($custom_params->pkey=='minwidth') $this->_oparams->minwidth=$custom_params->pvalue;
            if ($custom_params->pkey=='maxwidth') $this->_oparams->maxwidth=$custom_params->pvalue;
            if ($custom_params->pkey=='minheight') $this->_oparams->minheight=$custom_params->pvalue;
            if ($custom_params->pkey=='maxheight') $this->_oparams->maxheight=$custom_params->pvalue;
        } 
        return true;    
    } else {
        return false;
    }                   
}
```

Is it possible to write this data as:

```
$this->_oparams->$pkey=$custom_params->pvalue;
```

so I can avoid listing all the parameters?

In the code later I check parameters in this way:

```
if (!empty($this->_oparams->maxheight)) $htmlout.="\t\t\t\t<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"maxheight".$rowx->id."\" id=\"maxheight".$rowx->id."\" value=\"".$this->_oparams->maxheight."\" />";
```

Comment: Please change the title of your question to something more describing so other might benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
...
foreach ($custom as $custom_params)
    $this->_oparams->{$custom_params->pkey} = $custom_params->pvalue;
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks so much, square brackets - is one of many things I didn't know about php object programming, I will use it more right now!

Comment: They're actually called curly braces. You can also do something like `${$custom_params->pkey} = $custom_params->pvalue` so you can access the vars like so: `$minwidth`, `$maxwidth`. Please accept the answer if it's the answer you're looking for. Thanks.